# Handling a case of when my future returns a None in my play controller action method,

Tags: scala, playframework

I want to refactor by update action below to look a little more readable and also handle the failure case better

The `userService` has the following functions:

```
class UserService {
    def getUserByUsername: Future[Option[Int]] // which is the UserId
    def getUserById: Future[User]
}
```

My action looks like:

```
def update(userId: Int) = Action.async { implicit request =>
    request.body.validate[User] match {
        case JsSuccess(user, _) => {
            userService.getUserByUsername(user.username).map { userId => 
                userService.getUserById(userId.get).map { existingUser =>
                    userService.update(user.username)

                    Ok
                }
            }
        }
        case JsError(err) => Future.sucessful(BadRequest(err))
    }
}
```

1. How do I handle the situation where getUserByUsername returns a None?
2. Would this look cleaner if it was in a for comprehension, is it better style?

Comment: Blankman, you have manny compilation errors in this code snippet. Can you please complete it for a [mre]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some missing data in your questions such as case classes for the User model, userService class.
also better to attach the original function.

Anyways, I will do something as follows:

```
 def update(userId: Int) = Action { implicit request =>
    request.body.validate[User] match {
      case JsSuccess(user: User, _) => {
        val userId = getUserByUsername(user.username)
        userId match {
          case Some(userId) => {
            for {
              _ <- userService.getUserById(userId)
              _ <- userService.update(user.username)
            } yield Ok
          }.recover {
            case t: Throwable => 
              Metrics.errOnUpdate.increment() // Some metric to monitor 
              logger.error(s"update userId: $userId failed with ex: ${t.getMessage}") // log the error 
              InternalServerError(Json.toJson(Json.obj("error" -> "Failure occured on update"))) // return custom made exception to the client
          }
          case None => Future.successful(NotFound(s"No such user with ${user.username}"))
        }
      }
      case JsError(err) => Future.sucessful(BadRequest(err))
    }
  }
```

**Note:** If `.update` returns Future, you actually not waiting to `update` before returning `Ok` to the user, thus, if its fails, its still returns `Ok`.
To fix that, use flatMap and then map the value of `update` response.

You can also separate the recovering for the `getUserById` and `update` if you prefer.

---

Edit:

```
  def update(userId: Int) = Action { implicit request =>
    request.body.validate[User] match {
      case JsSuccess(user: User, _) => {
          getUserByUsername(user.username).flatMap {
             case Some(userId) => for {
                _ <- userService.getUserById(userId)
                _ <- userService.update(user.username)
              } yield Ok
             case None => Future.successful(NotFound(s"No such user with ${user.username}"))
          }
        }.recover {
          case t: Throwable =>
            Metrics.errOnUpdate.increment() // Some metric to monitor 
            logger.error(s"update userId: $userId failed with ex: ${t.getMessage}") // log the error 
            InternalServerError(Json.toJson(Json.obj("error" -> "Failure occured on update"))) // return custom made exception to the client
        }
      }
      case JsError(err) => Future.sucessful(BadRequest(err))
    }
  }
```

Comment: ```getUserByUsername``` returns a Future[Option[Int]], don't you have to call map and then match on that?   Yes update is a Future[Boolean]

Comment: From what you said: `userService.getUserByUsername  returns Option[Int] which is the UserId` - Its returns Future[Option[Int]] Instead? @Blankman

Comment: my mistake, it is a Future[Option[Int]], appreciate your help!!

Comment: If so, I edit my answer, note that there classes that are missing so maybe there some small changes you will need to do in order to compile it

Comment: If you want compiled answer, provide the case classes in order to run locally on our computer, i re-edit the Edit answer

Comment: It is not recommended to catch every throwable. You should catch only `NonFatal` exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

First, you probably need to use [`Option.fold`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/Option.scala#L262):

```
@inline final def fold[B](ifEmpty: => B)(f: A => B)
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
def update(userId: Int) = Action.async { implicit request =>
    def handleJsonErrors(errors: Seq[(JsPath, collection.Seq[JsonValidationError])]): Future[Result] = ???
    def updateUser(userWithoutId: User): Future[Result] = {
        for {
            userId <- userService.getUserByUsername(userWithoutId.username)
            _ <- userService.getUserById(userId.get)
            _ <- userService.update(userWithoutId.username)
        } yield {
            Ok
        }
    }

    request.body.asJson.fold {
        Future.successful(BadRequest("Bad json"))
    } {
        _.validate[User].fold(handleJsonErrors, updateUser).recover {
            case NonFatal(ex) =>
                InternalServerError
        }
    }
}
```